# Problem when using a case with the package connectivity_plus'

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I created a toast so that when the internet connection drops, a message appears alerting the user, and when the connection is restored, another message appears stating that the connection has been reestablished. However, on the web and Android, it works perfectly, but on iOS, the toast messages are being displayed in reverse order. I don't know what could be causing this.

I am using the packages another_flushbar and connectivity_plus.

Toast:

```
enum ToastType {
  success,
  warning,
}

dynamic getTopToast({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String text,
  double marginHeight = 56.0,
  required GlobalKey key,
  Duration? duration,
  ToastType type = ToastType.success,
  required Function onReload,
}) {
  Color? backgroundColor;
  Color? contentColor;
  String? icon;
  String? mainIcon;
  double? heightIcon;
  double? heightMainIcon;

switch (type) {
    case ToastType.success:
      backgroundColor = SystemTheme.successfullToastColor;
      contentColor = SystemTheme.successfullToastTextColor;
      icon = SystemImages.iconCheck;
      mainIcon = SystemImages.iconClose;
      heightIcon = 16.0;
      heightMainIcon = 24.0;
      break;
    case ToastType.warning:
      backgroundColor = SystemTheme.warningToastColor;
      contentColor = SystemTheme.primaryHoverColor;
      icon = SystemImages.iconWarning;
      mainIcon = SystemImages.iconRefresh;
      heightIcon = 24.0;
      heightMainIcon = 24.0;
      break;
  }

  return Flushbar(
    key: key,
    messageText: Container(
      height: 37,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: contentColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
    isDismissible: false,
    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
      icon,
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(contentColor, BlendMode.srcIn),
      height: heightIcon,
    ),
    mainButton: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (type == ToastType.success) {
          if (key.currentWidget != null) {
            (key.currentWidget as Flushbar).dismiss();
          }
        } else {
          onReload();
        }
      },
      icon: SvgPicture.asset(
        mainIcon,
        height: heightMainIcon,
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(contentColor, BlendMode.srcIn),
      ),
    ),
    duration: duration,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: marginHeight),
  ).show(context);
}
```

Stream in Screen:

```
  Future _connectionStream() async {
_connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
    .onConnectivityChanged
    .listen((ConnectivityResult result) async {
  if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
    setState(() {
      showTopToast = true;
    });
    getTopToast(
        context: context,
        key: flushBarKey,
        onReload: onReload,
        text: 'youAreOffline'.tr(),
        type: ToastType.warning);
  } else {
    (flushBarKey.currentWidget as Flushbar).dismiss();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    await getTopToast(
        context: context,
        key: successKey,
        onReload: onReload,
        text: 'theContentsIsAvailable'.tr(),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        type: ToastType.success);
    setState(() {
      showTopToast = false;
    });
  }
});
```

}